# I am having trouble converting a string with a UTC offset to a date in R using as.POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, utc

EXAMPLE

```
 foobar <- as.POSIXct("019-12-17 20:47:44.4799020 +00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z", tz = "UTC")
 foobar
 [1] NA
```

R Version
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

Answer (score 0):

Seems, the `"%z"` in the format is somehow causing trouble. Leaving it out works for me:

```
> as.POSIXct("019-12-17 20:47:44.4799020 +00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
[1] "0019-12-17 20:47:44 UTC"
```

Reason may be that `%z` expects a format like `+0000` (see [strptime documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime)).